# Single token refresh vs Long running refresh tokens (Django GraphQL JWT)

Tags: python, django, access-token, refresh-token, django-graphql-jwt

I used both **"Single token refresh" mode** and **"Long running refresh tokens" mode**.

**"Single token refresh" mode**:

```py
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=7),
}
```

**"Long running refresh tokens" mode**:

```py
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True, // This code is added.
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=7),
}
```

But I couldn't get a refresh token in **"Single token refresh" mode** running this graphql below:

```js
mutation {
  tokenAuth(username: "admin", password: "admin") {
    token
    payload
    refreshExpiresIn
    refreshToken // Here
  }
}
```

Then, I got this error:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"refreshToken\" on type \"ObtainJSONWebToken\". Did you mean \"refreshExpiresIn\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 20,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, I removed **"refreshToken" field** and ran this graphql:

```js
mutation {
  tokenAuth(username: "admin", password: "admin") {
    token
    payload
    refreshExpiresIn
    # refreshToken
  }
}
```

Then, I could get this result without error but I still couldn't get a refresh token:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "tokenAuth": {
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ3MDk2MTExLCJvcmlnSWF0IjoxNjQ3MDk1ODExfQ.5AY0HGqqmy3KwW1Gb_DFO99hIvJJh_AEngRH7hSe4DM",
      "payload": {
        "username": "admin",
        "exp": 1647096111,
        "origIat": 1647095811
      },
      "refreshExpiresIn": 1647700611
    }
  }
}
```

Next, when I ran this graphql with **"refreshToken" field** in **"Long running refresh tokens" mode**:

```js
mutation {
  tokenAuth(username: "admin", password: "admin") {
    token
    payload
    refreshExpiresIn
    refreshToken // Here
  }
}
```

I could get a refresh token successfully:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "tokenAuth": {
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ3MDk1ODg0LCJvcmlnSWF0IjoxNjQ3MDk1NTg0fQ.MOfdeD4P8SNNtCu3cm83qchqZr2aMo_ToWx_NchFiuE",
      "payload": {
        "username": "admin",
        "exp": 1647095884,
        "origIat": 1647095584
      },
      "refreshExpiresIn": 1647700384,
      "refreshToken": "9f82f2044942bdce8501c8caf026f93765ee7289" // Here
    }
  }
}
```

As long as I know, for **JWT**, normally there are 2 tokens **Access token** and **Refresh token** but why couldn't I get a refresh token in **"Single token refresh" mode**? Additionally, what is the difference between **"Single token refresh" mode** and **"Long running refresh tokens" mode**?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, in **"Single token refresh" mode**, you can get only one **Single token** and **Single token** is the combination token of **Access token** and **Refresh token** so **Single token** has 2 functions of both **Access token** and **Refresh token** so with only one **Single token**, you can do 2 things **"access resources(Access token function)"** and **"refresh Single token(Refresh token function)"**. You cannot get an access token and a refresh token separately in **"Single token refresh" mode**. That's why you couldn't get a refresh token in **"Single token refresh" mode**.

In **"Long running refresh tokens" mode**, you can get both **Access token** and **Refresh token** separately which is what you expect and want. In **"Long running refresh tokens" mode**, you can do more settings such as [Per-cookie](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/refresh_token.html#per-cookie), [Unlimited refresh](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/refresh_token.html#unlimited-refresh), [One time only use refresh token](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/refresh_token.html#one-time-only-use-refresh-token) and [Clear refresh tokens](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/refresh_token.html#clear-refresh-tokens).